# How do you use natspec comments to provide a confirmation text?

Tags: solidity, metamask

According to [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#comments):

> Additionally, there is another type of comment called a natspec
>   comment, for which the documentation is not yet written. They are
>   written with a triple slash (`///`) or a double asterisk block (`/** ... */`) and they should be used directly above function declarations or statements. You can use Doxygen-style tags inside these comments to
>   document functions, annotate conditions for formal verification, **and provide a confirmation text which is shown to users when they attempt to invoke a function**.

But I tried this with MetaMask:

```
  // Sell a ticket. Validate that the email associated to the buyer doesn't have a ticket already
  /// Buy Ticket!
  function buyTicket(string fullname, string email) {
    // ...
  }
```

And the text did not show up.

Is there something else that needs to be done? Or is it because MetaMask does not support this yet?

Comment: It seems an issue was created about this issue 
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2501 and closed later because of technicall shortcomings of the current definition of natspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MetaMask does not support this yet. We’ll need to research more on how to retrieve this data from published contracts, feel free to give us a head start by sharing your thoughts in a fresh GitHub issue: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/new